# Density plot using a list of integers

Tags: javascript, d3.js, kernel-density, density-plot

I'm building upon this example: https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/density_basic.html

However, instead of loading the data from a CSV file, I want to construct the density plot using a list of integers. Like this:

```
const list = [0, 0, 4, 19, 42, 75, 117, 165, 209, 238, 255, 255, 241, 220, 199, 181, 168, 162, 160, 159, 158, 156, 155, 151, 147, 142, 139, 135, 129, 123, 117, 111, 103, 96, 92, 86, 81, 78, 74, 70, 65, 61, 56, 50, 46, 42, 39, 36, 34, 32, 30, 28, 27, 25, 23, 21, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 14, 13, 12, 11, 11, 10, 9, 9, 8, 8, 8, 7, 7, 7, 6, 6, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8];
```

How can I do this?

Comment: please elaborate more - what is your question and what did you try so far?

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!-- Code from d3-graph-gallery.com -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<!-- Load d3.js -->
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>

<!-- Create a div where the graph will take place -->
<div id="my_dataviz"></div>


<script>

  // set the dimensions and margins of the graph
  var margin = { top: 30, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 50 },
    width = 460 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  // append the svg object to the body of the page
  var svg = d3.select("#my_dataviz")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform",
      "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

 /* YOUR LIST */
  const list = [94.0, 145.0, 251.0, 218.0, 265.0, 98.0, 66.0, 80.0, 52.0, 63.0, 92.0, 80.0, 228.0, 91.0, 58.0, 91.0, 101.0,]

  // add the x Axis
  var x = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, 1000])
    .range([0, width]);
  svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

  // add the y Axis
  var y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([height, 0])
    .domain([0, 0.02]);
  svg.append("g")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

  // Compute kernel density estimation
  var kde = kernelDensityEstimator(kernelEpanechnikov(7), x.ticks(40))
  var density = kde(list)

  // Plot the area
  svg.append("path")
    .attr("class", "mypath")
    .datum(density)
    .attr("fill", "#69b3a2")
    .attr("opacity", ".8")
    .attr("stroke", "#000")
    .attr("stroke-width", 1)
    .attr("stroke-linejoin", "round")
    .attr("d", d3.line()
      .curve(d3.curveBasis)
      .x(function (d) { return x(d[0]); })
      .y(function (d) { return y(d[1]); })
    );



  // Function to compute density
  function kernelDensityEstimator(kernel, X) {
    return function (V) {
      return X.map(function (x) {
        return [x, d3.mean(V, function (v) { return kernel(x - v); })];
      });
    };
  }
  function kernelEpanechnikov(k) {
    return function (v) {
      return Math.abs(v /= k) <= 1 ? 0.75 * (1 - v * v) / k : 0;
    };
  }

</script>
```

Remove the lines that import the data from a csv, but leave the rest of the code as is.

```
d3.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/holtzy/data_to_viz/master/Example_dataset/1_OneNum.csv", function(data) { // remove

/* leave this code */

} // remove
```

update the density to `var density = kde(list)`

Answer (score 1):

As a complement to the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57752183/5768908), the original code you linked uses `d3.line()` for creating the path with a green fill. That's not a clever way to do it, because the fill can be anywhere. For instance, this is how **your array** will look like:

```html
<!-- Code from d3-graph-gallery.com -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<!-- Load d3.js -->
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>

<!-- Create a div where the graph will take place -->
<div id="my_dataviz"></div>


<script>

  // set the dimensions and margins of the graph
  var margin = { top: 30, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 50 },
    width = 460 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  // append the svg object to the body of the page
  var svg = d3.select("#my_dataviz")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform",
      "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

 /* YOUR LIST */
  const list = [0, 0, 4, 19, 42, 75, 117, 165, 209, 238, 255, 255, 241, 220, 199,
  181, 168, 162, 160, 159, 158, 156, 155, 151, 147, 142, 139, 135, 129,
  123, 117, 111, 103, 96, 92, 86, 81, 78, 74, 70, 65, 61, 56, 50, 46,
  42, 39, 36, 34, 32, 30, 28, 27, 25, 23, 21, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15,
  14, 14, 13, 12, 11, 11, 10, 9, 9, 8, 8, 8, 7, 7, 7, 6, 6, 5, 5, 5, 5,
  5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4,
  4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8];

  // add the x Axis
  var x = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, 1000])
    .range([0, width]);
  svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

  // add the y Axis
  var y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([height, 0])
    .domain([0, 0.03]);
  svg.append("g")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

  // Compute kernel density estimation
  var kde = kernelDensityEstimator(kernelEpanechnikov(7), x.ticks(40))
  var density = kde(list)

  // Plot the area
  svg.append("path")
    .attr("class", "mypath")
    .datum(density)
    .attr("fill", "#69b3a2")
    .attr("opacity", ".8")
    .attr("stroke", "#000")
    .attr("stroke-width", 1)
    .attr("stroke-linejoin", "round")
    .attr("d", d3.line()
      .curve(d3.curveBasis)
      .x(function (d) { return x(d[0]); })
      .y(function (d) { return y(d[1]); })
    );



  // Function to compute density
  function kernelDensityEstimator(kernel, X) {
    return function (V) {
      return X.map(function (x) {
        return [x, d3.mean(V, function (v) { return kernel(x - v); })];
      });
    };
  }
  function kernelEpanechnikov(k) {
    return function (v) {
      return Math.abs(v /= k) <= 1 ? 0.75 * (1 - v * v) / k : 0;
    };
  }

</script>
```

As you can see, not what you expect.

So, instead of `d3.line()`, use the correct tool for the task, which is `d3.area()`:

```
d3.area()
    .curve(d3.curveBasis)
    .x(function (d) { return x(d[0]);})
    .y1(function (d) { return y(d[1]);})
    .y0(y(0))
```

Here is the result:

```html
<!-- Code from d3-graph-gallery.com -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<!-- Load d3.js -->
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>

<!-- Create a div where the graph will take place -->
<div id="my_dataviz"></div>


<script>

  // set the dimensions and margins of the graph
  var margin = { top: 30, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 50 },
    width = 460 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  // append the svg object to the body of the page
  var svg = d3.select("#my_dataviz")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform",
      "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

 /* YOUR LIST */
  const list = [0, 0, 4, 19, 42, 75, 117, 165, 209, 238, 255, 255, 241, 220, 199,
  181, 168, 162, 160, 159, 158, 156, 155, 151, 147, 142, 139, 135, 129,
  123, 117, 111, 103, 96, 92, 86, 81, 78, 74, 70, 65, 61, 56, 50, 46,
  42, 39, 36, 34, 32, 30, 28, 27, 25, 23, 21, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15,
  14, 14, 13, 12, 11, 11, 10, 9, 9, 8, 8, 8, 7, 7, 7, 6, 6, 5, 5, 5, 5,
  5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4,
  4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8];

  // add the x Axis
  var x = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, 1000])
    .range([0, width]);
  svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

  // add the y Axis
  var y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([height, 0])
    .domain([0, 0.03]);
  svg.append("g")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

  // Compute kernel density estimation
  var kde = kernelDensityEstimator(kernelEpanechnikov(7), x.ticks(40))
  var density = kde(list)

  // Plot the area
  svg.append("path")
    .attr("class", "mypath")
    .datum(density)
    .attr("fill", "#69b3a2")
    .attr("opacity", ".8")
    .attr("stroke", "#000")
    .attr("stroke-width", 1)
    .attr("stroke-linejoin", "round")
    .attr("d", d3.area()
      .curve(d3.curveBasis)
      .x(function (d) { return x(d[0]); })
      .y1(function (d) { return y(d[1]); })
      .y0(y(0))
    );



  // Function to compute density
  function kernelDensityEstimator(kernel, X) {
    return function (V) {
      return X.map(function (x) {
        return [x, d3.mean(V, function (v) { return kernel(x - v); })];
      });
    };
  }
  function kernelEpanechnikov(k) {
    return function (v) {
      return Math.abs(v /= k) <= 1 ? 0.75 * (1 - v * v) / k : 0;
    };
  }

</script>
```